# Differential equation : $y'=(x+y+1)/(x-y+2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question related to differential equations. I have to solve the following equation: 
$$
    y'=(x+y+1)/(x-y+2)
$$
However I don't see what I should do. In my seminar we used
$$
    y'=(x+y)/(x-y) 
$$
so I guess my problem should be somehow related to this one... don't know how though? Any ideas?

Comment: Oh!I'm sorry!I'm new here!Thank you,though!

Comment: Note that $$z(x)=y\left(x-\tfrac32\right)-\tfrac12$$ solves the differential equation $$z'(x)=\frac{x+z(x)}{x-z(x)}$$ which you said you could solve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign constants so that

$$(x+a)+(y+b)=x+y+1\text{ and }(x+a)-(y+b)=x-y+2.$$

The resulting system
$$
a+b=1,\quad a-b=2
$$
should be easy to solve.